# Query on concatenated fields across tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, pattern-matching

I have 2 tables in PostgreSQL `a` & `b`.

```
CREATE TABLE a
(
  id serial PRIMARY,
  name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE b
(
  id serial PRIMARY,
  name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  a_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT a_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a (id) 
);
```

Additionally, I have these 2 partial indexes on `b` to ensure that `b.name` is unique if `a` is null else the pair `(a.name, b.name)` is unique.

```
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx1 ON b (name, a_id) WHERE a_id IS NOT NULL;
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx2 ON b (name) WHERE a_id IS NULL;
```

If I want to query a string that is of the form: `a.name + ' ' + b.name`, is this the most efficient way to do it ? Is there anyway I can create an index that also ensures the uniqueness of `(a.name, b.name)` and use that to efficiently query it?

```
SELECT * FROM b
INNER JOIN a on b.a_id = a.id
WHERE CONCAT(a.name, ' ' , b.name) = 'some string';
```

I need an exact lookup, `LIKE` / `CONTAINS` is not needed.

Comment: Is there a need in your system that  the combination of (a.name, b.name) should be unique or are doing it just for performance?

Comment: Can't you split "some string" into "some" and "string" and do two comparisons?

Comment: I was able to create a functional index `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxa ON a (length(name), name) ;` (same for b). The optimiser uses this if `(length(a.name) = 4 AND length(b.name) = 4)` etc is added to the where clause, but it is unable to untangle `(length(a.name) + length(b.name) = 9)` Another way would be to store the length in an extra column and use a trigger function to maintain it.

Comment: @ Srikanth Uniqueness is required. @GordonLinoff No, the composite string is an external input. @ joop My understanding is that functional index work on same table only.

Comment: This is a tricky problem. Can you tell us more about the nature of the strings? Can `a.name` and `b.name` contain space characters (`' '`)? Can the search pattern contain multiple space characters? `External input` does not clarify what the string can look like. What is the minimum length of `a.name` and `b.name`? Can either of them be an empty string (`''`)? Do you still want the space in front of `b.name` in this case? Why do you use `varchar(50)` instead of just `varchar` or `text`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thank you for all the pertinent questions. `a.name` is name of pharma companies & `b.name` is name of medicine. They can contain multiple spaces, ampersand, numbers. It isn't possible to decompose the concatenated string back to `a & b` accurately. There are no restrictions on min length. It is possible to have an entry with no `a.name` (hence the partial index to uniquify on `b` alone if foreign key `a` is NULL). The space in front of `b` is not needed in that case. `varchar(50)` is arbitrary as of now.

Comment: How would you distinguish between 'Pfizer Walter' & 'Miller Drops' and 'Pfizer' & 'Walter Miller Drops'? A clear separation of company and medicine would be the better approach for this reason alone. The query would be simpler, too ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I see what you are saying and agree that would be a better approach in general. However, for this project, the requirement dictates that only fully qualified names would be accepted as a single string & rest will return no results (not targeting generic text search) i.e. only exact matches for the concatenated string are needed. A valid input can have 2 forms (i) `"b.name"` for generic stuff & (ii) `"a.name b.name"` for branded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need an additional `UNIQUE` constraint to fulfill your requirement:

> else the pair `(a.name, b.name)` is unique.

```
CREATE TABLE a (
 , id   serial PRIMARY KEY
 , name text UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

#### [**`MATERIALIZED VIEW`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-creatematerializedview.html)

That would work fast in *any* case: a [**`MATERIALIZED VIEW`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-creatematerializedview.html) with concatenated strings. Since `a` and `b` are linked, we only get as many rows as there are in `b`, no Cartesian product.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ab AS
SELECT b.a_id, b.id, concat_ws(' ', a.name, b.name) AS abname
FROM   b
LEFT   JOIN a ON a.id = b.a_id;
```

Since you only use equality, a simple b-tree index does the trick now:

```
CREATE INDEX ab_abname_idx ON ab (abname);
```

And the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ab
-- optionally (left) join to a and b ...
WHERE  abname = 'some string';
```

- `LEFT JOIN` is essential to include rows from `b` with `a_id IS NULL`.
- [`concat_ws()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) only inserts the space where `a.name` isn't `NULL`.
- Refresh the materialized view according to your access patterns. That may be the tricky part if you have concurrent write access.

#### Without `MATERIALIZED VIEW`

```
'some string' LIKE (a.name || '%')
```

is not [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). Index support is not possible. You would have to reverse the expression:

```
a.name = left('some string', length(a.name))
```

which is still not sargable. You would have to do it step-by-step:

```
a.name = left('some string', 1) OR
a.name = left('some string', 2) OR
a.name = left('some string', 3) OR
...
```

And this can be supported with indexes. Related answer on dba.SE:

- [Algorithm for finding the longest prefix](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43415/algorithm-for-finding-the-longest-prefix/43444#43444)

I would use a recursive CTE to find all matches ...